# Issue updating text with textview

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have built my own adapter that inflates a custom view that i created. That view contains a TextView tag that's associated with an author.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/author"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="John Smith" />
```

My problem is that when i go to populate that view, even if the object i am loading the data from (currentStory) contains a not null value, it still doesn't populate.

```
if (currentStory.getAuthor() == null)
    holder.author.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
else
    holder.author.setText(currentStory.getAuthor());
```

While debugging the code, I check the object and its state after the above condition and the Text attribute is populated with the correct data. When i let it run, it doesn't show the correct.

Does anyone have any idea on what i might be doing wrong or what i missed?

Comment: -Is the visibility set to `VISIBLE` before setting the text?

Comment: what does it show? Seems gone won't show a thing.

Comment: add different background color for TextView so that you can identify if TextView is invisible or if TextView content was not updated.

Comment: You must call holder.author.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE); in your else statement as well.

Comment: use `holder.author.setVisibility(View.GONE);` or `holder.author.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: Can you give us more information about your adapter? Is the `currentStory` variable with the correct values? Try to put `holder.author.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` inside the else clause.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this could solve your problem, but please try this

```
  holder.author.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (currentStory.getAuthor() == null)
                    holder.author.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                else
                    holder.author.setText(currentStory.getAuthor());
            }
        });
```

Comment: my problem was black screen when internet was not enabled but after using this thread problem solved. Thanks